# WEB API GET call causes Could not find file when code moved to host

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, webclient

Here is the error, works fine via VS locally but I get this error once I move it to the TEST server. I would assume its some server setting that isn't allowing the process access but if there is a work around anyone knows, I would appreciate it. I'm hitting a json GET api

```
An error has occurred via the CCR Referrals application. See the exception details below for further explanation.
```

> System.Net.WebException: Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\mxy=445544'. ---> System.Net.WebException: Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\mxy=445544'. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\mxy=445544'. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async) at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint) at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest&

```
string API_URL = (string)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_URL"];
string username = "TheDudeAbides";
string password = "xyz1234";
string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

//THE COMPLETED API URL plus the rn to lookup
API_URL = API_URL + "rn="+rn;

try
{
    //get th json results from the response from the URL call
    using (WebClient client2 = new WebClient())
    {

        //tell the call to use basic authorization and add the credentials to the client call
        client2.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + credentials;
       var responseOK = client2.DownloadString(PRES_API_URL);
       List<Protocol> listProts = Service.GetOpenProtsAppTable();

        if (responseOK != null)
        {
                if (responseOK != "")
                {  
                    JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(responseOK);
                    foreach(JObject item in jsonArray)
                    {

                          enrollment pe = new Patient_Enrollment();                                 
                          //Find the protocol ID from the jSON response
                          var itemProperties = item.Children<JProperty>();
                          var protocolElement = itemProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "protocol");
                          var protocol = protocolElement.Value; 
                    
                        Protocol prot = listProts.FirstOrDefault(i => i.protocolId_Display == protocol.ToString());
                        if (prot != null)
                        {
                            pe.IprotocolId = prot.protocolId.ToString().Replace("-", "");
                            pe.IshortTitle = prot.shortTitle;
                            pe.IstudyId = Convert.ToString(prot.studyId);

                            //instatiate the PRES API information into Patient_Enrollment objects, to compare to what Referrals has for enrollment on the MRN.
                            enrollments.Add(pe);
                        }                              

                    }

                }
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    //email that the API is down.
    Email.SendErrorNotification("API Down", e.ToString());
}

}
```

Comment: It looks as if your test server isn't configured to handle your application as code but treats it as files on disk. Is your code in ASP.NET Core and if so, have you installed the ASP.NET Core hosting bundle on the server?

Comment: The code is NOT ASP.NET Core. The DEV server is managed by another group. I guess since I can't make changes to the server is there a workaround?

Comment: Do you know if the exception you posted comes from your code or from the JSON API you are calling? Are you calling the same API URL from Visual Studio and from the dev server?

Comment: Same URL on both VS and DEV server, the exception is coming from my code via Elmah.

Comment: @Simmetric how do I test or tell if the server is doing this and the more important question how to I change it?

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: Modified the code above to make it simple and take out non-necessary items. Hopefully someone has some ideas.

Comment: Here is some basic advice for clean code: 
Only 1 line in any try catch. (abstract the code inside into a lower layer) 
Build abstract layers for your code. 
Each method, if it is void has 1 effect, when the method is a leaf, in your execution chain. 
if it is a get, it has 0 effects, and only returns the return type. 

Variable names, class names, interface names, etc. Are NOUNS! 
Method names are VERBS. 

private methods are code smell in when following SOLID, which any OOP should be following. 

have unit test coverage close to 100% when the above suggestions are done.

Comment: Follow this, and you will understand why your code isn't doing what you expect. The unit test will reveal it. 

If people did this, this site would get like 1 question a month, TOPS...

Comment: It is difficult if you don't have to the server you host it. Can you at least confirm that the. net framework is installed and same on the both (prime suspect)? Are there any certificates that need to be read as files so it may indicate  folder access restrictions? From the error nothing refers to your code, or hve you forgot to paste that?

Comment: This is the only example of this exception on the internet... if you don't get an answer its time to rebuild your test server. *Like what is this?* `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\mxy=445544`

Comment: I would suggest using `HttpClient` with json serialization like `System.Text.Json` instead of `WebClient`

Comment: Can we see the value for PRES_API_URL?  My suspicion is that it's resolving to an address on the client machine and not the server.  I would also break out the code as mentioned by Morton Bork specifically around smaller methods for better error handling.

Comment: I'm getting "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined" now when I run the app on the DEV server? Any new ideas?  I changed techniques to use HTTPClient instead of WebClient.

Comment: Getting a consistent error now. The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. Any suggestions?